# Why Google's Places service get me the same cities two times with different attributes (place_id,coords ecc..)?

Tags: json, web-services, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want to get only one unique result from the web service autocomplete:

This is my request : 
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=napoli ita&type=(cities)&language=en&key={API_KEY}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=napoli%20ita&type=(cities)&language=en&key=AIzaSyAk332BpTp9Ay4oiQ2RrG06TTL1qkHN2RU)

and this is the response

```
{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "description": "Naples, Metropolitan City of Naples, Italy",
      "id": "b2aaa9753e7bab447d0a3f71a2336c8bb96c3cac",
      "matched_substrings": [
        {
          "length": 6,
          "offset": 0
        },
        {
          "length": 3,
          "offset": 37
        }
      ],
      "place_id": "ChIJ6_p622YIOxMRfriMZcxDOtI",
      "reference": "ClRCAAAA6jM0wQfsTkmn2G9JhSrJK1XN5mdK0nFiE_iNiSpmOpzWV9E5cE7Bn5hnxEZy7EfQrTm5uDagf82Sjc-6wBhd7ZtYgLUXArJNYcI1WogVH6USEGz0Cao3FSrzmLlNiP5zhqAaFKa_hu7uIBoAvErvdqhSfF-r7QfZ",
      "structured_formatting": {
        "main_text": "Naples",
        "main_text_matched_substrings": [
          {
            "length": 6,
            "offset": 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text": "Metropolitan City of Naples, Italy",
        "secondary_text_matched_substrings": [
          {
            "length": 3,
            "offset": 29
          }
        ]
      },
      "terms": [
        {
          "offset": 0,
          "value": "Naples"
        },
        {
          "offset": 8,
          "value": "Metropolitan City of Naples"
        },
        {
          "offset": 37,
          "value": "Italy"
        }
      ],
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political",
        "geocode"
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Napoli, Metropolitan City of Naples, Italy",
      "id": "4d33ea47519b8f9c04635b1a9bae12f04197b99d",
      "matched_substrings": [
        {
          "length": 6,
          "offset": 0
        },
        {
          "length": 3,
          "offset": 37
        }
      ],
      "place_id": "ChIJRw3rhP-wOxMRP2qkGuYBOxo",
      "reference": "ClRCAAAAZZJtsiAUKI1qcM0-X_srZwzECGVTK4FtCwEVnUxa7xZJOV5VIyjYDXjqZ6miFEQ1_-yge9sGrbYsQAxOUgriaYZj1juHpRJiKijVRFztW40SEFtfe85oDpHJndMpB2KVxw4aFFKZyol4j79xsZ6f6GlA9osp-uSh",
      "structured_formatting": {
        "main_text": "Napoli",
        "main_text_matched_substrings": [
          {
            "length": 6,
            "offset": 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text": "Metropolitan City of Naples, Italy",
        "secondary_text_matched_substrings": [
          {
            "length": 3,
            "offset": 29
          }
        ]
      },
      "terms": [
        {
          "offset": 0,
          "value": "Napoli"
        },
        {
          "offset": 8,
          "value": "Metropolitan City of Naples"
        },
        {
          "offset": 37,
          "value": "Italy"
        }
      ],
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political",
        "geocode"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

You can see that it return me the same city with different place id , name , coords but same type . Why this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google has two different localities with the same name in the same province of Italy that leads to exactly the same description in autocomplete.

Have a look at place ID ChIJ6_p622YIOxMRfriMZcxDOtI.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJ6_p622YIOxMRfriMZcxDOtI

And now at place ID ChIJRw3rhP-wOxMRP2qkGuYBOxo

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJRw3rhP-wOxMRP2qkGuYBOxo

Both have the same name, the same administrative area level 1 and administrative area level 2. The administrative area level 3 is different, but it doesn't appear in the description of autocomplete, so you cannot distinguish these localities.

I don't have local knowledge, so I cannot say if this data is correct. If you believe this data is wrong, feel free to let Google know about this as specified in this support page:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

Hope it helps!